# error: cannot find symbol import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

Tags: react-native

I installed Jetifier to resolve an issue with react-native-gesture-handler but now I'm getting this error:

```
> Task :expo-constants:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
C:\ioweu\node_modules\expo-constants\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\constants\ConstantsService.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
                          ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: package androidx.annotation
C:\ioweu\node_modules\expo-constants\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\constants\ConstantsService.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
  @Nullable
   ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class ConstantsService
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I'm working with React Native and Android Studio. I'm still new to all of this so any help is appreciated.

Here are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    implementation project(':react-native-screens')
    implementation project(':react-native-reanimated')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    addUnimodulesDependencies()
}
```

To solve my earlier errors, I followed the content here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25483#issuecomment-508446776, which I understand changed my project to use AndroidX.

To solve these two new errors, I tried adding the line `implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:+"` to my gradle.build dependencies and then run ./gradlew clean but it didn't work or I did it wrong. I think I'm going about it the wrong way.

Edit: I added `implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0"` but it didn't solve anything yet.

Edit 2: I tried the guide here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility#recommended-use-android-studio-to-migrate-your-app. Steps 1, 3 and 4 were the only ones that seemed to apply to me.

This resulted in the following error:

```
error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

Edit 3: Issue (with my splash screen class) was fixed by adding `implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0"` to my build.gradle and replacing

```java
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

with

```java
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

My issue is now fixed. I'm sorry for asking questions which may seem like a hinderance to people more well versed in this.